# Synonymify [reentrant] and [reentrancy]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Title says it all, really. 74 questions in [reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrant), 113 in [reentrancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrancy), many even tagged with both, probably as users are (understandably) confused which to pick. According to their wikis, one is a bit broader than the other, but it's a difference without consequence, really. I propose the two should at the very least be made synonyms; I would also be okay with [reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrant) being burninated and retagged to [reentrancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrancy).

(`<rant>` Additionally, there's also [reentrantlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrantlock) and [reentrantreadwritelock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reentrantreadwritelock) which apparently are all about Java classes of the same name. Does every little Java class deserve its own tag? `</rant>`)

Comment: Re: your `<rant>`, remember we even have **multiple method tags**  ([tag:console.writeline]/[tag:console.readline])

Comment: Don't you mean *[synonymise](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synonymise#Verb)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to file a synonym request. Pick the tag, "learn more" to get the tag wiki page. Then hidden in the bottom right corner, "suggest tag synonym". Then this pops up.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reentrant/synonyms

2500 rep is needed to post a request.

Comment: If I do that, won't one of the tags be stranded? I was under the impression the proper procedure is to initiate discussion, then start the community on migrating one tag to the other? (Then again, this is my first such initiative)

Comment: @Amadan They will be merged into one. If one tag should be replaced by the other, then indeed the proper way is to make a meta post. It would rather be a burninate request. Although in this case we can probably merge them first and then get rid of the unwanted one after, without causing any harm to any posts.

Comment: Bleh. No go. Need score 5 in [tag:reentrancy], which I don't happen to have. :P (I think [tag:reentrancy] should be primary, and [tag:reentrant] the alias)

Comment: @Amadan Ach... and I don't have any rep in that tag either.